# Who are said to have the firstfruits of the Spirit in Romans 8:23?

Tags: romans, referent-identification, paul, niv

Romans 8:23 NIV

23 Not only so, ***but we ourselves, who have the firstfruits*** of the Spirit, groan inwardly as we wait eagerly for our adoption to sonship, the redemption of our bodies

Is it

1)Apostles

2)Jews

3)Church

Who are said to have the firstfruits of the Spirit in the above text?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clear that Paul - talking to those in Rome, the church, the believers.

> those who are in Christ Jesus v1

> so that the requirement of the Law might be fulfilled in us v4

> However, you are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit of God dwells in you v9

> So then, brethren v12

> fellow heirs with Christ v17

> revealing of the sons of God. v19

> but also WE ourselves

So it's not the Jews (though some might be there), but it is the brethren which naturally includes Apostles, teachers, elders etc - that which makes up the brethren and 'sons of God'.

The firstfruits is the spirit deposit given to believers. This works in them until their change at Christ's return. It is a symbol of the 'First fruit', Jesus, who dwells in us with the Father through the spirit. (2 Corinthians 1:21-22, Eph 1:14)